# Problemas al exportar DataTable a Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Net.Mail;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Productos_Sin_Parametro_Ax
{

 class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Program a = new Program();
        a.sendEmail("Productos sin parámetros en Axapta");
     }

    public void sendEmail(string asunto)
    {
        WMSOLEEntities db = new WMSOLEEntities();
        var values        = db.VW_PRODUCTOS_SIN_PARAMETROS.ToList();

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        SmtpClient clienteSmtp = new SmtpClient();
        string emisor          = string.Empty;
        string password        = string.Empty;

        emisor   = "helpdesk@ole.com.do";
        password = "Ole123Ole123";

        MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
        mensaje.From        = new MailAddress(emisor);
        mensaje.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("desarrollador1@ole.com.do"));
        //mensaje.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("richard.nova@ole.com.do"));
        //mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress("margarita.nicolas@ole.com.do"));
        //mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress("karem.mengo@ole.com.do"));
        mensaje.Subject    = asunto;
        mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;

        List<VW_PRODUCTOS_SIN_PARAMETROS> contentList = new List<VW_PRODUCTOS_SIN_PARAMETROS>();
        List<Object> contentListToExcel = new List<Object>();

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            contentListToExcel.Add(new
            {
                Codigo         = item.CODIGO,
                Descripcion    = item.DESCRIPCION,
                Unidad_Empaque = item.UND_EMP,
                Existencia     = item.EXISTENCIA
            });
        }

        Program b = new Program();
        b.ToDataTable(contentListToExcel);

        clienteSmtp.Host = "184.154.228.10";
        clienteSmtp.Port = 2525;
        clienteSmtp.EnableSsl = false;
        clienteSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        clienteSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emisor, password);
        clienteSmtp.EnableSsl = false;

        if (values.Count() > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //clienteSmtp.Send(mensaje);
                Console.WriteLine("Correo enviado");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error al enviar el correo" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No existen productos");
        }

    }

    public DataTable ToDataTable(List<Object> list)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("CODIGO");
        dt.Columns.Add("DESCRIPCION");
        dt.Columns.Add("UNIDAD EMPAQUE");
        dt.Columns.Add("EXISTENCIA");

        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = s;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        MethodResult = dt;

        Program c    = new Program();
        var filename = "Productos sin parámetros ";
        c.ToExcelFile(dt, filename);

        return MethodResult;

    }

    public bool ToExcelFile(DataTable dt, string filename)
    {
        bool Success = false;

        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Sheet 1");

        if (filename.Contains("."))
        {
            int IndexOfLastFullStop = filename.LastIndexOf('.');

            filename = filename.Substring(0, IndexOfLastFullStop) + ".xlsx";
        }

        filename = filename + ".xlsx";

        wb.SaveAs(filename);

        Success = true;

        return Success;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Como ven, estoy intentando exportar unos datos que extraigo desde un View en SQL Server, el problema es que al ejecutar el VIEW me devuelve una lista de tipo **VW_PRODUCTOS_SIN_PARAMETROS**, y cuando hago la conversión de la lista a DataTable me toma el objeto completo con todas sus propiedades y datos en una sola columna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues eso es exactamente lo que haces en tu código, "en la columna 0 poner el objeto completo":

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = s;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

no porque el objeto tenga el mismo nombre en sus propiedades que las columnas significa que lo hará de forma automática, debes poner en cada columna el valor que quieres, algo así:

```
 foreach (var s in list)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["CODIGO"] = s.Codigo;
        dr["DESCRIPCION"]= s.Descripcion;
        dr["UNIDAD EMPAQUE"]= s.Unidad_Empaque;
        dr["EXISTENCIA"]= s.Existencia;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya resolví el problema.